# Как посчитать MSSQL размер всех блоб полей в разрезе таблиц?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Пробовал `sp_spaceused` - там нет. Datalength - даёт резутьтат, но нужно его как-то связать с полями...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для конкретной таблицы можно сформировать запрос вида

```
select *
from (
        select
            'TableName' as TableName,
            cast(sum(datalength([BlobColumn1])) as bigint) as [BlobColumn1],
            cast(sum(datalength([BlobColumn2])) as bigint) as [BlobColumn2]
        from [TableName]
    ) t
    unpivot (Size for [ColumnName] in ([BlobColumn1], [BlobColumn2])) u
```

Для всех таблиц то же самое можно сделать динамическим запросом.

По `sys.columns` выбрать LOB-столбцы (признаком этого является `max_length = -1`). Binary-LOB можно отфильтровать, присоединив `sys.types` (с условием `name = 'varbinary'`) к `sys.columns`:

```
declare @dynamicSql nvarchar(max);

with t as (
    select t.object_id, a.TableName
    from sys.schemas s
        join sys.tables t on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        cross apply (select quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name)) a(TableName)
),
c as (
    select c.object_id, c.name
    from sys.columns c
        join sys.types ct on ct.system_type_id = c.system_type_id and ct.name = 'varbinary'
    where c.max_length = -1
)
select @dynamicSql = stuff(
    (select
        'union all select * from (select ''' + t.TableName + ''' as TableName, ' + c.ColList
            + ' from ' + t.TableName + ')t unpivot (Size for [ColumnName] in (' + c2.ColList + ')) u '
    from t
        cross apply (
            select stuff((
            select ', cast(sum(datalength(' + quotename(c.name) + ')) as bigint) as ' + quotename(c.name)
            from c
            where c.object_id = t.object_id
            order by c.name
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
        ) c(ColList)
        cross apply (
            select stuff((
            select ', ' + quotename(c.name)
            from c
            where c.object_id = t.object_id
            order by c.name
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
        ) c2(ColList)
    where c.ColList is not NULL
    order by t.TableName
    for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, len('union all') + 1, '');

exec sp_executesql @dynamicSql;
```

Если нужны данные по столбцам всех LOB-типов (включая `nvarchar(max)` и `xml`), то нужно убрать из запроса `sys.types`.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш запрос, покрутил, немного переписал попроще  `select @dynamicSql=  (select stuff((select ' union select  '''+t.name+''' id,sum(' +  stuff((select '+isnull(datalength(['+c.name+']),0)'  from  sys.columns c  where  
  system_type_id in (select system_type_id from sys.types where name like '%var%') 
  and c.object_id=t.object_id for xml path('')),1,1,'' )+ ') size from ' + t.name from sys.tables t 
for xml path('')),1,6,''))   + ' order by 1'
`, но спасибо за идею.

Comment: @nick_n_a, без фильтра `с.max_length = -1` у вас запрос захватит не только lob-ы, но также и столбцы наподобие `varchar(20)`.

Comment: Подскажите плз, mssql varchar не считается blob? Он хранится в секции данных, или в отдельном stream как blob (почти все СУБД считают что varchar - blob)? Именно varchar я считал blob. Ваш запрос мне выдал мало полей, и не одно varchar.

Comment: @nick_n_a, к LOB-типам относят _varbinary(max), varchar(max), nvarchar(max), xml_, т.е. типы, которые могут иметь (почти) неограниченную длину. BLOB - это _Binary_-LOB, т.е., напр., _varbinary(max), xml_. Типы _varchar(max), nvarchar(max)_ иногда называют CLOB (Character-LOB), но и те и другие чаще просто LOB. Типы _varchar, nvarchar, varbinary_, у которых длина не _max_ обычно не относят к LOB. Впрочем, иногда их называют SLOB (_Short_-LOB) из-за способа хранения, они хранятся в IN_ROW_DATA, если для них там нашлось место, но если нет - то в ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA (кот. устроены подобно LOB_DATA).