# Список таблиц в базе и количество строк

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Как можно получить список пользовательских таблиц в БД и количество строк в каждой из них?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630259/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-mssql-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86

Comment: @nick_n_a не вижу там ничего похожего на мой вопрос...

Comment: Там пример как сделать множественный запрос к всем таблицам, но можно взять строки из "кеша" (в ответе тут).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так (через [sp_spaceused](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188776(v=sql.120).aspx))

```
declare @t table (name varchar(255), row varchar(255), reserved varchar(255), data varchar(255), index_size varchar(255), unused varchar(255))
insert into @t
exec sp_msforeachtable N'exec sp_spaceused ''?''' 
select * from @t
-- Часть ниже необязательна, нужна мне для удобства что б подбить итоги
union select 'total:',  sum( cast( row as int)),  
cast( sum( cast(replace(reserved,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(255)),
cast( sum( cast(replace(data,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(255)),
cast( sum( cast(replace(index_size,' KB','') as int)) as varchar(255)),
null from @t
```

Функция даёт кешированое значение которое может отличатся от `select count(*) from table1`, но данная ф-ция не блокируется ожиданием удаления или другими процессами синхронизации. Подсмотрено на [sql.ru/forum](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1044733/poluchenie-spiska-vseh-tablic-na-servere)

---

Теоретически можно сделать `select count(*) from tables` аналогичным способом, этот метод работает **дольше** не смотря даже на `with(nolock)` (который раза в 2 ускоряет выборку за счёт игнора блокировок), а результат не хуже

```
declare  @t table ( name varchar(255), ct int)
insert into @t
exec sp_msforeachtable N'sp_sqlexec''select''''?'''',count(*)from ? with(nolock)''';     
select * from @t
```

поэтому рекомендую первый способ.

Comment: точно только пользовательские таблицы будут?

Comment: Да, если конечно не выбрана системная база, её обычно не выбирают в default.  Можно ещё дописать `using База_данных` таблицы которой нужны.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант, вручную можно посчитать как-то так.

```
use ......;

declare @cdata table (tname varchar(255), cnt int);

DECLARE tc CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT s.name + '.' + o.name
    FROM sys.objects AS o
    LEFT JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON (o.schema_id = s.schema_id)
    WHERE type = 'U' --and s.name = 'data'
    ORDER BY s.name, o.name;

DECLARE @tname varchar(255);
DECLARE @sql varchar(255);

OPEN tc;

FETCH NEXT FROM tc INTO @tname;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'select '''  + @tname + ''', count(*) as cnt from ' + @tname;
    PRINT @sql;

    insert into @cdata exec(@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM tc INTO @tname;
END;

CLOSE tc;
DEALLOCATE tc;


SELECT ISNULL(tname, 'Итого') as tname, sum(cnt) as cnt
FROM @cdata
WHERE cnt > 0
GROUP BY tname WITH ROLLUP 
ORDER BY cnt desc
```

Comment: Всёравно через sp_spaceused быстрее.

Comment: Зачем создавать темповые таблицы? C ними больше мороки. У меня чего-то они не заработали `#cdata`

Comment: а я и не утверждал  что этот метод вообще лучше чем то. разве что вы не можете вызывать хранимки.

Comment: @nick_n_a а через `exec` не получится вставить в табличную переменную, вроде. не помню точно, но по какой-то причине когда было написано  именно так.

Comment: Получится так `insert into @cdata exec(@sql);` только из `@sql` убрать insert тогда.

Comment: да, действительно, затупил что-то :)